# When i type import pygame, i get an error that reads:

Tags: python, pygame

The error traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: It means the `python` is not able to find that module. You have to install `pygame` first inorder to use it. You can use `pip install pygame` to install it.

Comment: Have you installed **pygame** module ? If not, do this `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

this means you haven't installed pygame. Run this in your command line:

```
pip install pygame
```